# 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare add: cannot convert name "Everyone" to a SID. An invalid combination of parameters was specified

Tags: samba, shared-folders

After upgrading 19.10 to 20.04 samba is not working right. Trying to share Documents using the GUI I am getting this error:

> **'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare add: cannot convert name "Everyone" to a SID. An invalid combination of parameters was specified..**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I added this

```
interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0
```

and it started working

Comment: Added it to what file?

Comment: @Lolwhites samba config, under global.

Comment: The line is already in my samba config file.

Comment: @Lolwhites did you restart the service? Or reboot?

Comment: My issue turned out to be different: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258069/unable-to-creatre-samba-shares-in-20-04/1258264#1258264