# Unable to create Samba shares in 20.04

Tags: networking, samba

I share three or four folders over my network, but since upgrading to 20.04, I am unable to create new ones. When I try, I get the error message

> 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare add: cannot convert name "Everyone" to a SID. > An invalid combination of parameters was specified..

Existing shares continue to be accessible.

I tried the fix given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236826/net-usershare-returned-error-255-net-usershare-add-cannot-convert-name-ever) but the line in question is already in my /etc/samba/smb.conf file.

Edit: Entering *net usershare info --long* yields the folowing:

[C&L Docs]

path=/home/laurie/Sync/C&L Docs

comment=

usershare_acl=S-1-1-0:F,

guest_ok=y

Entering *testparm* yields:

Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

Global parameters

[global]

```
client max protocol = NT1

log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

logging = file

map to guest = Bad User

max log size = 1000

name resolve order = bcast host lmhosts wins

obey pam restrictions = Yes

pam password change = Yes

panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u

server role = standalone server

server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

unix password sync = Yes

usershare allow guests = Yes

idmap config * : backend = tdb
```

Comment: Please post the output of the following commands: `net usershare info --long` AND `testparm -s`

Comment: See edited post

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your error. You created a paradox.

> client max protocol = NT1

Samba disables NT1 on the server side of your install yet you specify the maximum protocol the client can use to NT1. Ain't gonna happen.

I'm almost certain you meant to add this in smb.conf:

```
client min protocol = NT1
```

If I do that and restart smbd: `sudo service smbd restart` I can create the share without the error message.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!